# How to compact a merge between two Pandas Dataframes with NaN and duplicate join keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Not sure what the exact terminology for this is - but let's say, I have these two files:

dataA.csv:

```
event,car,bike,bus
63175,,18,
65641,45,9,
65805,,,54
68388,,65,
68388,,,39
73041,7,,18
79336,,44,
79423,,,5
```

dataB.csv:

```
event,car,truck,bike
69834,12,,
73704,,32,
74798,,,74
77290,29,,45
79336,,55,
88795,15,,4
88979,88,,
```

I want to merge/combine/join these tables with the "event" column as a join key; however, note that:

- Both .csv tables have missing values (NaN)
- Otherwise, the data stored in both tables is unsigned integer(s)
- Some column names repeat in both tables, others are unique to a table
- The "event" column (which is the "join key") in dataA has value 68388 in two rows (I call this a duplicate); and "event" value 79336 appears in both dataA and dataB (I also call this a duplicate)

I tried this code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

dataA = pd.read_csv("dataA.csv", dtype='Int64')
dataB = pd.read_csv("dataB.csv", dtype='Int64')

print("dataA:")
print(dataA)
print("\ndataB:")
print(dataB)

dataMerged = pd.merge(dataA, dataB, on='event', how='outer').sort_values('event', ignore_index=True)
print("\ndataMerged:")
print(dataMerged)
```

... and the output is:

```
dataA:
   event   car  bike   bus
0  63175  <NA>    18  <NA>
1  65641    45     9  <NA>
2  65805  <NA>  <NA>    54
3  68388  <NA>    65  <NA>
4  68388  <NA>  <NA>    39
5  73041     7  <NA>    18
6  79336  <NA>    44  <NA>
7  79423  <NA>  <NA>     5

dataB:
   event   car  truck  bike
0  69834    12   <NA>  <NA>
1  73704  <NA>     32  <NA>
2  74798  <NA>   <NA>    74
3  77290    29   <NA>    45
4  79336  <NA>     55  <NA>
5  88795    15   <NA>     4
6  88979    88   <NA>  <NA>

dataMerged:
    event  car_x  bike_x   bus  car_y  truck  bike_y
0   63175   <NA>      18  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
1   65641     45       9  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
2   65805   <NA>    <NA>    54   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
3   68388   <NA>      65  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
4   68388   <NA>    <NA>    39   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
5   69834   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>     12   <NA>    <NA>
6   73041      7    <NA>    18   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
7   73704   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>     32    <NA>
8   74798   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      74
9   77290   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>     29   <NA>      45
10  79336   <NA>      44  <NA>   <NA>     55    <NA>
11  79423   <NA>    <NA>     5   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
12  88795   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>     15   <NA>       4
13  88979   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>     88   <NA>    <NA>
```

Note that the merge already "compacted" the "event" value 79336 - I have only one row with "event"==79336, and it contains the values from both files; however, there are still rows with "event"==68388 - and, I'd want only a single "car" and "bike" columns. In other words, I want the output result to be this (manually edited, hopefully I don't have errors):

```
    event   car  bike   bus  truck
0   63175  <NA>    18  <NA>   <NA>
1   65641    45     9  <NA>   <NA>
2   65805  <NA>  <NA>    54   <NA>
3   68388  <NA>    65    39   <NA>
4   69834    12  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
5   73041     7  <NA>    18   <NA>
6   73704  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     32
7   74798  <NA>    74  <NA>   <NA>
8   77290    29    45  <NA>   <NA>
9   79336  <NA>    44  <NA>     55
10  79423  <NA>  <NA>     5   <NA>
11  88795    15     4  <NA>   <NA>
12  88979    88  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
```

Note that in my data, typically I do not have "conflicts", that is:

- Either one value is a number, the other is NaN (e.g. `dataA("event"=68388,"bike")=65`,`dataB("event"=68388,"bike")=<NA>`), in which case the output should contain the number (e.g. `out("event"=68388,"bike")=65`)
- Or both values are NaN (e.g. `dataA("event"=68388,"car")=<NA>`,`dataB("event"=68388,"car")=<NA>`), in which case the output should also contain NaN (e.g. `out("event"=68388,"car")=<NA>`)
- Or (very rarely) both values are the same number (e.g. `dataA("event"=50000,"ZZZ")=42`,`dataB("event"=50000,"ZZZ")=42`), in which case the output should also contain the same number (e.g. `out("event"=50000,"ZZZ")=42`)

How can I achieve this kind of "compacted merge" with Pandas?

PS: it would be also good to know how one would handle the case of a conflict - that is, there are different numbers competing for the same slot/cell in the output (e.g. `dataA("event"=90000,"ZZZ")=400`,`dataB("event"=90000,"ZZZ")=13`) - in this case, I'd like to write -1 in the output, which is a good enough indication of conflict in this case, given that valid data is unsigned integer. Since the data above does not contain such entries, just knowing this in principle would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
#dfA=dfA.mask(dfA.eq('<NA>'))
#dfB=dfB.mask(dfB.eq('<NA>'))
df=pd.concat([dfA,dfB],sort=True).groupby('event').first().reset_index()
Out[61]: 
    event bike  bus  car truck
0   63175   18  NaN  NaN   NaN
1   65641    9  NaN   45   NaN
2   65805  NaN   54  NaN   NaN
3   68388   65   39  NaN   NaN
4   69834  NaN  NaN   12   NaN
5   73041  NaN   18    7   NaN
6   73704  NaN  NaN  NaN    32
7   74798   74  NaN  NaN   NaN
8   77290   45  NaN   29   NaN
9   79336   44  NaN  NaN    55
10  79423  NaN    5  NaN   NaN
11  88795    4  NaN   15   NaN
12  88979  NaN  NaN   88   NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks @YOBEN_S - that seems to work; however, for some reason, with that code, "bike" and "car" columns end up as Int64 columns in my case; but "bus" and "truck" are floats (?!) - but managed to get around that with `pd.concat([dataA,dataB],sort=True).astype('Int64').groupby('event').first().reset_index()`. Also, not sure if that `.mask` method is really required?