# Understanding .groupby().first() when compacting Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Since I'm not sure of the exact terminology - let's say, I have this file:

dataA.csv:

```
event,car,bike,bus
63175,,18,
65641,45,9,
65805,,,54
68388,,65,
68388,,,39
73041,7,,18
79336,,44,
79423,,,5
```

Reading this with `dataA = pd.read_csv("dataA.csv", dtype='Int64')`, we get a pandas DataFrame:

```
dataA:
   event   car  bike   bus
0  63175  <NA>    18  <NA>
1  65641    45     9  <NA>
2  65805  <NA>  <NA>    54
3  68388  <NA>    65  <NA>
4  68388  <NA>  <NA>    39
5  73041     7  <NA>    18
6  79336  <NA>    44  <NA>
7  79423  <NA>  <NA>     5
```

There are two rows, where "event" column has the same value (what I call "duplicates"):

```
3  68388  <NA>    65  <NA>
4  68388  <NA>  <NA>    39
```

... and I'd like them to be "compacted" (is this the right word?) to a single row, such that actual values (where available) are there, instead of NaN (that is, NA):

```
3  68388  <NA>    65    39
```

From [How to compact a merge between two Pandas Dataframes with NaN and duplicate join keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147790/how-to-compact-a-merge-between-two-pandas-dataframes-with-nan-and-duplicate-join) I got the answer, that I should use `.groupby(...).first()` - and indeed, it works; this script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__) # 1.0.2 for me

dataA = pd.read_csv("dataA.csv", dtype='Int64')
print("dataA:")
print(dataA)

# make sure Pandas prints entirety of DataFrame
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

dataCompact = dataA.groupby('event').first() ##***
print("\ndataCompact:")
print(dataCompact)
```

eventually prints:

```
dataCompact:
        car  bike   bus
event
63175  <NA>    18  <NA>
65641    45     9  <NA>
65805  <NA>  <NA>    54
68388  <NA>    65    39
73041     7  <NA>    18
79336  <NA>    44  <NA>
79423  <NA>  <NA>     5
```

... which is what I wanted, so it works.

However, upon a closer look, I realized I don't really understand how this works - that is, I cannot really tell what `.first()` specifically refers to in this case; and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html does not help me much, because it states "*Method to subset initial periods of time series data based on a date offset.*" (and most other introductory pages online follow the dates example), - but here I do not use dates.

So, I did some experiments - basically changing the line marked with `##***` in the above code, and looking at printouts.

First, if I use this line instead:

```python
dataCompact = dataA.groupby('event').apply(lambda x: "{} ({}): {}".format(type(x), len(x), x.values.tolist())) ##***
```

... I get this printout:

```
dataCompact:
event
63175                             <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (1): [[63175, <NA>, 18, <NA>]]
65641                                <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (1): [[65641, 45, 9, <NA>]]
65805                             <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (1): [[65805, <NA>, <NA>, 54]]
68388    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (2): [[68388, <NA>, 65, <NA>], [68388, <NA>, <NA>, 39]]
73041                                <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (1): [[73041, 7, <NA>, 18]]
79336                             <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (1): [[79336, <NA>, 44, <NA>]]
79423                              <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (1): [[79423, <NA>, <NA>, 5]]
dtype: object
```

From this, I gather that - essentially, `groupby('event')` provides a DataFrame for each unique value of 'event' column:

- if the value is unique in the original dataset, that DataFrame has a single row; however
- if it is a "duplicate" value, we get a DataFrame with two rows (or as many rows, as there are "duplicates" of that particular value).

So, `.first()` must take a DataFrame with N>=1 rows as input, and return a single row.

However, this is where my confusion starts - I'd read `.first()` to refer to returning the *first* of the N>=1 input rows; but in that case, the values would not have been "compacted" (that is, slots that have actual numbers replacing slots with `<NA>` (undefined values)); - instead, all other rows but the first would be dropped! And that is not what happens here ...

So, I tried to simulate what `.first()` does, by writing my own lambda handler for `.apply()`:

```python
def proc_df_first(x):
  # here we get a DataFrame with single row, if "event" (groupby arg) is a unique value;
  # or a DataFrame with as many rows, as there are repeated rows with "event" of same value ("duplicate")
  if len(x) == 1:
    return x
  elif len(x) > 1:
    # create empty return DataFrame (eventually it will only have a single row)
    retdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = x.columns)
    #return retdf # is empty, so is skipped in final result of .groupby.apply
    # must populate rowdata first, then assign via .loc (SO:17091769)
    for icol in x.columns:
      coldata = x[icol] # is Series
      thisval = pd.NA # initialize the "compact" single value we want to set for this column (eventually derived from all the row values in this column)
      for idx, val in coldata.iteritems():
        #print("***", idx, val, val is pd.NA) # `val is None` is always False; `val==pd.NA` always prints `<NA>`; `val is pd.NA` is correct
        if thisval is pd.NA:
          if val is not pd.NA:
            # found the first non-NA value; save it, and stop looking further
            thisval = val
            break
      # store saved non-NA value into return DataFrame
      retdf.at[ x.index[0], icol ] = thisval # SO: 13842088
    return retdf

dataCompact = dataA.groupby('event').apply(lambda x: proc_df_first(x)) ##***
```

... which eventually prints:

```
dataCompact:
         event   car  bike   bus
event
63175 0  63175  <NA>    18  <NA>
65641 1  65641    45     9  <NA>
65805 2  65805  <NA>  <NA>    54
68388 3  68388   NaN    65    39
73041 5  73041     7  <NA>    18
79336 6  79336  <NA>    44  <NA>
79423 7  79423  <NA>  <NA>     5
```

... which is essentially the same result that `.groupby('event').first()` does (aside from the duplicated "event" column (would that be a hierarchical label?), and the index column).

So, here are my questions:

- As per the above, I'd say that `.first()` returns the first non-NA per-column value in a set of rows, resulting in a single-row representation of the set of rows - is this correct?
- Why, for crying out loud, did I get NaN in the "car" column of the output for "event"==68388 - when I tried to handle everything internally as "Int64" (with the corresponding `pd.NA` value)? I'm aware I can do `dataA.groupby('event').apply(lambda x: proc_df_first(x)).astype('Int64')` and get `pd.NA` everywhere - but given that I iterate the whole table element-by-element already, I wouldn't want yet another loop over the table - just to get rid of a single float NaN. What could I do in my handler, to ensure that the return from `proc_df_first()` in `.apply()` always results with `pd.NA` values, if that particular value is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas are 2 different `first` functions, which are different:

[`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`DataFrame.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html).

Here is used first, `first` per groups.

> As per the above, I'd say that .first() returns the first non-NA per-column value in a set of rows, resulting in a single-row representation of the set of rows - is this correct?

Yes, you are right, but it is something like long term bug, [6732](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6732) and [8427](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427). Still in [pandas 1.0.1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6732#issuecomment-596536820).

> Why, for crying out loud, did I get NaN in the "car" column of the output for "event"==68388

Unfortunately I think because bug.

Comment: Many thanks for confirming this @jezrael - I'd note, since I need to do "compacting" in this case, and `GroupBy.first` does that for me, I would not call it a bug `:)` - it's just not documented in detail properly. Additionally, it turns out that initializing with `retdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = x.columns).astype('Int64')` fixes the NaN problem. As in the OP code, by default columns with "object" dtype are generated for empty DF; however, .dtypes is a read-only property (and also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/36462257) - so casting with `.astype()` is the only thing applicable here.

Comment: @sdaau - Exactly, it is like `'something like'` bug, so  I think in future it should be officialy confirmed functionality ;)